# What is the purpose of private parameterless constructor in C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I just received *C# in Depth* by Jon Skeet in the mail and am not following the discussion on page 7-8.

> We now have a private parameterless constructor for the sake of the
>   new property-based initialization. (p. 8)

It is not clear to me how the property-based initialization requires a parameterless constructor, if that's what "for the sake of" implies.

```
class Product
{
   public string Name { get; private set;}
   public decimal Price { get; private set;}
   public Product (string name, decimal price)
   {
     Name = name;
     Price = price;
   }
   Product(){}
   .
   .
   .
}
```

What is the purpose of `Product(){}`  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code:

```
Product p = new Product { Name = "Fred", Price = 10m };
```

is equivalent to:

```
Product tmp = new Product();
tmp.Name = "Fred";
tmp.Price = 10m;
Product p = tmp;
```

So the parameterless constructor is still required - it's only called from within the class in the sample code, so it's okay for it to be private.

That's not to say that *all* object initializers require a parameterless constructor. For example, we could have:

```
// Only code within the class is allowed to set this
public string Name { get; private set; }
// Anyone can change the price
public decimal Price { get; set; }

public Product(string name)
{
    this.Name = name;
}
```

And then use that like this, from anywhere:

```
Product p = new Product("Fred") { Price = 10m };
```

There's a lot more detail later on in the book, of course (chapter 8 IIRC).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Jon. So the private constructor is being invoked implicitly "behind the scenes".

Comment: @Tim: Yes, that's right. You can make it explicit too even in the parameterless case: `new Product() { Name = ..., Price = ... };`

Comment: What would happen, when the private parameterless constructor was not defined/implemented?

Comment: @user1767754: Then you'd always have to specify constructor arguments in the object initializer, as per the last example.

Comment: hello I just bought your book and there is a little thing. I've pasted your code with the parameterless constructor and VS is still saying that I can't use the initialization. As it would not see the private constructor and it want's me to use the one with parameters before I will initialize the properties. Maybe I understand something wrong?

Comment: @Rafal_Koscinski: The example in the book calls the constructor from within the same class, which is valid. If you want to call a constructor from *outside* the source of that class, you'll need to make the constructor internal or public.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.You showed above that this is done so that we could do something like this: Product p = new Product { Name = "Fred", Price = 10m }; But when we do that VS is telling that we can't because the constructor is private. Sorry but I feel a little bit confused about it. Of course if I want it to use outside the code I should make it private but I don't see the usage in the class of that constructor. One thing I see is the list initialized with the constructor with parameters :(

Comment: @Rafal_Koscinski: I'm afraid I'm finding it hard to parse your comment. The code you've quoted there is calling a parameterless constructor - so it can only be used when the parameterless constructor is accessible to the calling code. In the sample code I provided, the constructor is only used within the class itself, so it's fine for it to be private.

Comment: Ahhhhhh NOW I GET IT !!!!!! You use it so that you could do INSIDE of the class something like this: new Product {Name="something", Price = something}. I was looking from the wrong perspective. If you did not have this one you would have to use in the method the "dot " initializer, is that correct?

Comment: @Rafal_Koscinski: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the method the dot initializer" - if you mean setting properties explicitly, then yes.

Comment: yeas I meant that ;) never the less I've discovered thanks to you that I was looking on the subject from the long perspective ;) And yes that's what I've meant. Thank you very much Mr. Skeet for time spent :) and on that ocasion I wish you Merry Christmas and Happy New Year :)